cannot open url with gdal from within azure docker environment
I am wanting to open a file link (href) that was retrieved from Microsoft planetary computer like this
import pystac_client
import planetary_computer
from osgeo import gdal

catalog = pystac_client.Client.open(
        "https://planetarycomputer.microsoft.com/api/stac/v1",
        modifier=planetary_computer.sign_inplace,
    )

search = catalog.search(
        collections=["sentinel-2-l2a"],
        datetime="2024-07-16",
        query={"s2:mgrs_tile": {"eq": "18NWL"}},
    )

# Retrieve and return the collection of items found by the search
items = search.item_collection()

href = items[0].assets["SCL"].href

ds = gdal.Open(href)


Locally, in my windows environment this works with no problem.
But when I build my docker environment and deploy it in azure cloud I get the following error
An error occurred while creating a virtual connection to the DAP server:Error while reading the URL: https://sentinel2l2a01.blob.core.windows.net/sentinel2-l2/18/N/WL/2024/07/16/S2A_MSIL2A_20240716T152651_N0510_R025_T18NWL_20240716T235619.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T18NWL_A047355_20240716T152653/IMG_DATA/R20m/T18NWL_20240716T152651_SCL_20m.tif.ver. The OPeNDAP server returned the following message: Not Found: The data source or server could not be found. Often this means that the OPeNDAP server is missing or needs attention. Please contact the server administrator.
The link however is valid and I can download the file even from within the cloud.
I am using a rather old gdal version (3.2.2) because of install-conflicts in the docker build.
But this version executes locally as well. So I am a bit confused to what the problem really is.
The problem really seems to be tied to gdal.Open(href) which is behaving differently within my local and the docker environment.
My first guess was the gdal config options being different.
But it seems almost all of them are 'None' anyways.
Is there one or multiple that I SHOULD be setting?
I have tested gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_SKIP", "DODS") and
gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL", "YES"), with no success.
Or does anyone know of a bug that is fixed in an older version?
Or could the different behaviour be tied to windows / linux differences?
i am open to any suggestions

SOLVED: I managed to solve it myself afterall. add '/vsicurl/'+href
thanks to the thread of https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues/129
